# How to treat keybinding as input to search?

Tags: key-bindings, search

In some cases [0/4]

- Keybinding is too much!
- Keybinding naming is not intuitive. like projectile-rails-console has keybinding [prefix + r].
- Some keybindings naming will conflict under the intuitive principle. For example: projectile-rails-find-test, projectile-rails-find-template, [t].
- Borrow the idea from helm: search, filter, narrow to one candidate.

So I want to create an emacs extension to do better job.
For example, I have following keybindings bind to those commands.

```
    [C-c C-r r] -- projectile-rails-console
    [C-c C-r t] -- projectile-find-test
    [C-c C-r T] -- projectile-find-current-test
    []          -- projectile-goto-template-at-point
```

Below is a list of things I'd like to achieve:

- UI Features

  - Borrow the idea from helm: search, filter, narrow to one candidate.
  - Borrow from “guide-key”, show the keybindings popup.
- Core

  - When you input a prefix, like [C-c], then the extension start popup the following keybindings like “guide-key”, then user can continue press key just like normal use “guide-key”, but user also can type key like [tem], this will filter out keybindings which bind to command projectile-rails-goto-template etc.
  - I know I can archive this by directly use [M-x] to select command, but it is not intelligent, Emacs separated keybinding and command. I want to provide a smart way to do both in one place.
  - The big problem is how to let Emacs treat the following key input as search input, instead of continuing key press.

I created an github reposition at here: [emacs-intelligent-key-guide](https://github.com/stardiviner/emacs-intelligent-key-guide).

Does anybody knows that is possible? And how? I need some hints.
Thanks in advanced.
And if you're interested in this project, welcome to contribute.

My real question is:
How to treat following keybinding behind prefix map as normal input for searching commands?

Comment: This question risks being closed as unclear. Do not just post a URL to your real question and say "*Go see this and tell me whether it is possible.*" If you want help here then pose a clear, specific question here.

Comment: I see, I will copy the real question to here.

Comment: Thanks. But taking a brief look at that page, you will need to pull a more specific question out of it to add here. As it stands now, it risks being closed as too broad. This is a Q&A site: specific questions & specific answers.

Comment: I don't know how to describe it, but I will try.

Comment: Thanks. The better you can help people understand what you need, the better the help you will get.

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: @politza do you have any idea about how to implement this?

Comment: I was joking. You want to treat any, in the context of the current prefix keys, unbound key as part of some search string ?

Comment: @politza yes, I think xuchunyang's way is a good hint.

Comment: How does a user know wheter some character will execute a command or narrow the help buffer, while avoiding the problem that you're trying to solve ?

Comment: Usually keybindings is shorter then commands. It filter candidates like helm etc completion frameworks, keep input will go to the command, and set a delay will execute the keybindings. Delay is not good, not efficient, I need get a better idea. You're right.

Answer (score 1):

Try `describe-buffer-bindings`:

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "result")
  (describe-buffer-bindings (current-buffer) (kbd "C-c") nil))
```

will insert list of key binds that use `C-c` as prefix in current buffer to `result` buffer.

By using this function, `prefix ?` (or `prefix C-h`) lists all key binds that start with `prefix` in the `*Help*` buffer, [`helm-descbinds`](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm-descbinds) even provides a helm interface for `prefix ?` i.e., type `prefix ?` and then search & select a command in helm.

P.S. Reading `guide-key`/`helm-descbinds`'s source code to learn how they are implemented might be helpful since it seems like you want to make a helm interface for `guide-key`.